# What encryption model does Magento1 use?

Tags: magento-1, security, password

I want to know what encryption methods are used by Magento.

Is it simple md5 or salted or SHA? Where can I look into it in detail?

I looked for code for md5 encryption in `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption`, which is used to encrypt passwords. I can also see `encrypt` and `decrypt`. What are they used for? Encrypting user info or something else?

Answer (score 9):

Encryption is done via the `Mage_Core_Model_Encryption` class.

Hashing runs via the method `hash` which uses MD5. Not sure why did didn't go with SHA but it should be sufficient.

Encrypting data for later use is done using the `encrypt` method that use the `Varien_Crypt` class that by default relies on [Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) to do it's job.

Since it uses a `factory` pattern you can easily use other encryption methods as well in theory by adding a class file in the `app/code/local/Varien/Crypt` directory.

The `Varien_Crypt_Mcrypt` class is a wrapper for PHP Mcrypt used to encrypt data with the key given in the `local.xml` file under node path `global/crypt/key`. If you want to add your own encryption class you can probably use that class best as an example

Comment: thanks , i looked code for md5 encryption here "Mage_Core_Model_Encryption" which method is use to encrypt password 

i can also see encrypt and decrypt for what are they using encrypting user info or ?

Comment: "Not sure why did didn't go with SHA" - they do in Magento Enterprise (very questionable to intentionally use less secure methods in CE, if you ask me...)

Comment: @fschmengler so thats what $15.000 buys you these days... :P

Comment: @mour passwords are done with the MD5 method and a salt string that is stored separated with a ':' after the password

Comment: what to do if we want to make it secure