# How admin password stored in database?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, password, encryption-key

I want to create an API point where the admin user can update their password, but I don't know what encrypt method used to encrypt the admin password and save it in the database, roughly what I want is like this:

```
$data = array(
          'user_id' => '1',
          'password' => 'magento2',
          'firstname' => 'Jane'
        );

$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);

if(isset($data['password')) $data['password'] = $this->encryptPassword($data['password']);
$user->addData($data);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.x, the admin password is saved as **`CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX')`**, where '**qX**' is salt value for encryption and it can be any other string.

If you don't use salt concatenation, i.e. use a blank salt value, then you can simply use:

```
MD5('password')
```

to save the password of the admin user.

I hope I was clear enough to explain.

Please let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's changed recently it's MD5 See this post (found with a quick google search)
[What encryption model does Magento1 use?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59401/what-encryption-model-does-magento1-use)